# var within firebase set

Tags: variables, firebase, dynamic, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create some dynamic JSON based on a value of a name like below

```
this.merchantFirebase.child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).update({
      this.props.data.name: {
        status: this.state.productSwitch
      }
    });
```

I was thinking this would create something like

```
this.merchantFirebase.child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).update({
      latte: {
        status: this.state.productSwitch
      }
    });
```

but it is just given me an error of unexpected token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use a different notation for this:

```
var updates = {};
updates[this.props.data.name] = { status: this.state.productSwitch };

this.merchantFirebase.child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).update(updates);
```

By using square-bracket notation, JavaScript "knows" that it needs to evaluate `this.props.data.name` as an expression, instead of using it as the literal name of the property (as it tries to do in your code).